# Yii2 debug toolbar error 'Unable to find debug data tagged with ... '

Tags: php, debugging, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In a page on my site I receive this error about debug toolbar, as suggested in other answers at similar question:

1. The directory `/runtime` and all sub-dir have right chmod permissions, after some test I've tried with 777 mode but the error remains (is bad I know, but is only for test);
2. The index.data have not the tag which generate the error;
3. After run `composer update` command the error wasn't solved;
4. No error logs was generated in `runtime/logs` folder;
5. In a first time the xdebug module was not installed, after I've installed the extension error was not solved;
6. [Edit 1] The `/runtime` dir was be cleaned after every test

The debug module configurations:

```
`$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1'],
];`
```

The site is made by advanced template, someone have an idea about how I can solve this problem?

Comment: try to clear all runtime data entirely (remove everything except the .gitignore file)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is one thing I've not insert in my question but I've clear all elements inside runtime folder more times in every test. The last one is after your comment, this not solve my situation

Comment: xdebug is not related to debug toolbar

Comment: @AntonRybalko read [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1504#issuecomment-31146993) , seems can xdebug generates errors, for be clear I have add this on my question

Comment: @MarBer did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Yii2 advance template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced) has two runtime folders, the backend runtime and the frontend runtime

You need to clear one you are debugging.